# Changing default div scroll-x behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a div

```
    .dialog_container{

    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;

}
```

New div messages are appended to container:

```
$('.dialog_container').append('<div class="message_container"></div>')
```

The natural behaviour of container in case of `overflow-x:scroll` is clear. But I want the opposite, so that it would scroll and extend at the top when there are more elements than default container can contain, not at the bottom as usual. It's mainstream design in messengers and etc.

How could I implement that ? Google only helped with some plugins creating custom scroll tabs and stuff.

Comment: What is your exact requirement. Be more specific.

Comment: @DanPhilip overscroll-x behaviour but not at the bottom, but at the top of the div. I hope it's clear?

Comment: So you want horizontal scroll only at the top portion of the div.

Comment: @DanPhilip yes, some solutions or basic implementation concept

Comment: Can you post some references you found while searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to grab the height of the div, then use animate scrollTop to animate the entire height.

jQuery

```
$(".append").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $(".messages-container").append("<p>I'm a new message</p>");

  //Relevant jQuery start
  var height = $(".messages-container")[0].scrollHeight;
  $(".messages-container").animate({
    scrollTop: height
  });
  //Relevant jQuery end
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="messages-container">

</div>
<button class="append">
Append Message
</button>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/calder12/nasrk4fk/